# Is it possible to do ranges with variables using sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I was trying to use sed as follows:

```
sed -i "7,$n_line s/abcd/efgh/g" file
```

I am getting an error saying: unexpected `,'

Comment: Are you sure your $n_line is set? run this command: `n=2; sed -e "1,$n s/./z/g" <<< $'a\nb\nc\nd'` to see if works.

Comment: edit your answer to show the value of your variable "n_line"

Answer (score 1):

if `n_line` is set to a numeric value (i.e you are doing a range with line numbers (eg: 7,9), this will work as it is.

However, if `n_line` is set to a pattern (i.e you are doing range with line number and pattern(eg: 7,yyy), `unexpected`,'` will be returned as error. To resolve this, change your command to:

```
sed -i "7,/$n_line/ s/abcd/efgh/g" file
```

**Example:**

```
AMD$ cat File
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aayyyaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa

AMD$ cat Script
#!/bin/bash

echo "Example 1: n is numeric"
n=4
sed "2,$n s/a/b/g" File

echo ""
echo "Example 2: n is pattern (working case)"
n="yyy"
sed "2,/$n/ s/a/b/g" File

echo ""
echo "Example 3: n is pattern (error case)"
n="yyy"
sed "2,$n s/a/b/g" File

AMD$ ./Script
Example 1: n is numeric

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbyyybbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Example 2: n is pattern (working case)

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbyyybbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Example 3: n is pattern (error case)

sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "7,${n_line=0} s/abcd/efgh/g" file
```

Secure a bit to insure n_line is at least equal to 0 for the substitution (or any other wanted value). This does not check that the variable is a number or null